# ip address for virtualbox genymotion

Tags: ip, virtualbox, genymotion

I have a problem with Genymotion, previously I install Genymotion and use it with IntelliJ IDEA on windows 7. After a while I install a new windows(7) and install Genymotion and IntelliJ IDEA again. But at this time Genymotion cannot start. the below figure occure,

[image: click here to see message error]

Also I do all answers in the internet as below:

ipv4 address:192.168.56.1
DHCP server address:192.168.56.100
Attached to:Host-only adapter
Name: virtualbox host-only ethernet adapter
adapter type:virtio-net
Promiscuous mode : Allow VMs
The network adapter view is:

[image]

Also when I ping the IP address of DHCP server, the result is that it is not reachable.

Comment: Try to install latest virtual box uninstall previous one.  hope it works.

Comment: @SuhasB : I download VirtualBox as well as Genymotion from its website, So I think they are the latest versions...

Comment: Try to install DHCP server from this Link :http://www.dhcpserver.de/cms/download/  or uninstall everything and install again